# How to change the height of row at indexPath after table was reloaded?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

This question may look weird because there is a method:
`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I know, but it is called for every cell when table is loading.

In my case I need to change the height of ROW (**not the height  of cell in this row**) at some indexPath. How to do this?

In my `UITableViewController` as a delegate of cell I have following method:

```
func calendarEventCellWillChangeItsSize(cell: PLCalendarEventTableViewCell, size: CGFloat, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    cell.frame.size.height = size //I can simple change the size of cell

}
```

The question is:

**How to change height of the ROW at any indexPath inside this method?**

What is the difference?

[image]

The image presents 2 frames: the red one -> for row, the green one ->for cell. When I load table, I set the height 266, but when table is loaded within a cell, I count the cell height, and then I have to change its size. In this case I changed its size to 211. But it changed only cell height, not row for this cell... So there is empty space.

Comment: What is the difference between "the height of ROW" and "the height of cell in this row" ?

Comment: I attached example in question

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk, There is no such thing as a row in reality. `heightForRow:atIndexPath:` returns a height for a cell in that row. From the screenshot that you provided, I understand, that you want your cell to remain the same height, but to add a space under it. However, this space below will also be a part of a cell. You could achieve it via auto layout, I guess.

Comment: Why don't you put a variable to store the row that you want to change its size. Then under `heightForRow:atIndexPath` leave the other rows unaffected just when your index is the same as variable, change its height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: I usually add that to the rest of the tableView initialization code in my viewController's viewDidLoad.  Right after:  `[self.tableView registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyTableViewCell" bundle:nil]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`